# Set date to specific hour the next the day

Tags: apex

I'm using BusinessHours class and the add method. I need to set a date field to a specific hour the following day. Here is my pseudo code:

```
Datetime targetDate = system.now();
if(condition is met) {
MyDateField__c = BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, targetDate, ???); // need to set to 7pm the next day in EST timezone
}
```

How can I calculate to a specific hour the next day from the target date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `BusinessHours` if you are trying to set a specific time. I recommend you use `Datetime.newInstance(Date, Time)`:

```
Datetime target = Datetime.newInstance(
    Date.today().addDays(1),
    Time.newInstance(19, 0, 0, 0)
);
```